# Renaming columns in attribute table of joined data - integer data

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, attribute-joins, table

Using QGIS 2.14.4 (Essen). I am trying to join an excel for data about species surveys which were conducted at different locations, by blocks of area which is a separate shapefile I have already. I am able to convert the excel into a CSV, add this with "No geometry" and then join this to the Block data layer by using shared Block IDs found in both tables, however, when joining data the attribute table columns are named after the originally joined excel file e.g."Anchor D_1"; "Anchor D_2"
I found a solution here: [Renaming attributes/fields in shapefile attribute table using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75563/how-to-rename-attributes-fields-in-a-shapefile-attribute-table)

However, I seem to be unable to rename any column which contains Integer data (see image). Any answers?[image]

Comment: Thanks Joseph! Going back to my 2.12 (Lyon) version fixed the problem!

Comment: Most welcome, I posted the comment as an answer for the convenience of others along with a link to the bug report =)

Answer (score 2):

It would seem the *Table Manager* plugin does not like the `Integer64(10)` type fields. This seems to occur from **QGIS version 2.14.4 and above**.

Using QGIS 2.14.3 and below seems to allow the plugin to work they way it should as integer fields are recognised as `Integer(10)` type fields **which can be renamed**.

---

A [bug report](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15410) has been created for this issue.